# Reduce image file size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, ios4, uiimage

Is it possible to reduce the image size without changing dimension of image.Similar like photoshop does.

e.g If Actual image size 400Kb with dimension 400 X 300 and if I edit & save image has low resolution. Then the image size while be 250kb with dimension 400 X 300.

Note: I need to achieve transparency if image contains. 
I need to push this image server and the same image while be shown in website.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506871/image-compression-by-size-iphone-sdk

Comment: @Adam thanks for your fast response. If I compress iamge into JPEG transparency part will become white right...

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282830/uiimagepickercontroller-uiimage-memory-and-more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gif or png images cannot be compressed. They implement a build in compression algorithm and that's it.

The best solution in your case would be to save the png image as a jpeg with a solid color replacing the transparent color, then compress the jpeg image and save it.

When you'll need the image, you will convert the jpeg image to a transparent image, by using the CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors core graphics function.

[See this thread on how to make a color to transparent with core graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633722/how-to-make-one-color-transparent-on-a-uiimage)

Answer (score 4):

yeah it is possible .... see this code

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"anyImage.png"];

NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);
// 0.5 is float value it is 1.0 for same resolution

UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Thank You!

Comment: It removes transparency. Need to compress image with transparency.

Comment: You can't @Tushar-iOSdeveloper. You can just decrease the image dimension in case of png.

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth taking a look at this.
This is for jpegs, it really works, and the pictures look pretty much the same.
http://www.jpegmini.com/main/home